# Matrix multiplication method gives wrong result

Tags: cocoa, matrix-multiplication

I try to make a method to calculate the multiplication between two matrices, but I have got a problem with the result. Some lines are well calculated, but the others not. And when I run the program several times, the result change for these lines.

UPDATE 12/05/2016 : I updated the code with the solution.

Here is my matrix declaration :

```
float mat1[16];

mat1[0]  = 8.0; mat1[1]  = 2.0; mat1[2]  = 7.0; mat1[3]  = 0.0;
mat1[4]  = 2.0; mat1[5]  = 9.0; mat1[6]  = 0.0; mat1[7]  = 4.0;
mat1[8]  = 6.0; mat1[9]  = 0.0; mat1[10] = 6.0; mat1[11] = 4.0;
mat1[12] = 3.0; mat1[13] = 0.0; mat1[14] = 0.0; mat1[15] = 5.0;

NSLog(@"mat1 =");

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    NSLog(@"%f | %f | %f | %f", mat1[(i*4)+0], mat1[(i*4)+1], mat1[(i*4)+2], mat1[(i*4)+3]);
}

float *matResult = [self matrix2MultMatrix1:mat1 byMatrix2:mat1];

NSLog(@"matResult =");

for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    NSLog(@"%f | %f | %f | %f", matResult[(i*4)+0], matResult[(i*4)+1], matResult[(i*4)+2], matResult[(i*4)+3]);
}

free(matResult);
```

Here is my method :

```
- (float*)matrix2MultMatrix1:(float*)m1 byMatrix2:(float*)m2
{
    //BEFORE SOLUTION :
    //float result[16];

    //AFTER SOLUTION :
    float *result = (float*)malloc(16 * sizeof(float));

    // First line
    result[0]  = m1[0]*m2[0] + m1[1]*m2[4] + m1[2]*m2[8]  + m1[3]*m2[12];
    result[1]  = m1[0]*m2[1] + m1[1]*m2[5] + m1[2]*m2[9]  + m1[3]*m2[13];
    result[2]  = m1[0]*m2[2] + m1[1]*m2[6] + m1[2]*m2[10] + m1[3]*m2[14];
    result[3]  = m1[0]*m2[3] + m1[1]*m2[7] + m1[2]*m2[11] + m1[3]*m2[15];

    // Second line
    result[4]  = m1[4]*m2[0] + m1[5]*m2[4] + m1[6]*m2[8]  + m1[7]*m2[12];
    result[5]  = m1[4]*m2[1] + m1[5]*m2[5] + m1[6]*m2[9]  + m1[7]*m2[13];
    result[6]  = m1[4]*m2[2] + m1[5]*m2[6] + m1[6]*m2[10] + m1[7]*m2[14];
    result[7]  = m1[4]*m2[3] + m1[5]*m2[7] + m1[6]*m2[11] + m1[7]*m2[15];

    // Third line
    result[8]  = m1[8]*m2[0] + m1[9]*m2[4] + m1[10]*m2[8]  + m1[11]*m2[12];
    result[9]  = m1[8]*m2[1] + m1[9]*m2[5] + m1[10]*m2[9]  + m1[11]*m2[13];
    result[10] = m1[8]*m2[2] + m1[9]*m2[6] + m1[10]*m2[10] + m1[11]*m2[14];
    result[11] = m1[8]*m2[3] + m1[9]*m2[7] + m1[10]*m2[11] + m1[11]*m2[15];

    // Fourth line
    result[12] = m1[12]*m2[0] + m1[13]*m2[4] + m1[14]*m2[8] + m1[15]*m2[12];
    result[13] = m1[12]*m2[1] + m1[13]*m2[5] + m1[14]*m2[9] + m1[15]*m2[13];
    result[14] = m1[12]*m2[2] + m1[13]*m2[6] + m1[14]*m2[10] + m1[15]*m2[14];
    result[15] = m1[12]*m2[3] + m1[13]*m2[7] + m1[14]*m2[11] + m1[15]*m2[15];

    return result;
}
```

Xcode gives :

[image]

The right result must be :

```
| 110   34   98   36|
|  46   85   14   56|
|  96   12   78   44|
|  39    6   21   25|
```

Comment: Note that, the way you have the expressions for `mat[0]` through `mat[15]` fully written out, it's very difficult to tell at a glance whether or not the code is correct, or to modify it to work with matrices of different sizes. Consider using two or three nested `for` loops instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're declaring `float mat[16]` within the `matrix2MultMatrix1:byMatrix2:` method, once you leave the method, the memory pointed to by `mat` (and `result`) is left on the stack for other use.

What you want to do is allocate some memory explicitly in this method so that it will not be overwritten once you return it.

```
float *mat = (float *)malloc(16 * sizeof(float));
```

But whenever you allocate memory you must make sure you free it, so once you have finished with the result:

```
free(matResult);
```

Comment: That first line of code is invalid as is and will not compile. More than one way to fix it, you should pick the one you intended and edit your answer.

Comment: Thanks DanielGibbs ! It works ! But I have another question directly related with your answer. Where must I free the memory ? If I free it before `result` I lose the values, and if I free it after `result` I don't know if there is really a deallocation, because the program exit the function, before the free() instruction.

Comment: Don't `free` the result in the method, you need to `free` it in the method that called it, once you've finished using the result. In your example above this would be after you printed `matResult`.